# Random quote generator multiple quotes

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of arrays and i have to generate multiple random quotes. The user has to choose between 1 to 5 quotes to generate and which generator want to choose ( 1 or 2 ).

I started creating two generators and they are working fine but they are not working together.
any help?

I am new to Javascript.

```js
// sentences for generatorOne
let userChoice;
let generatorChoice;
let first = [
  ['Peace,', 'Love', 'Money', 'iPhones', 'Beauty', 'Happines'],
  [' will be', ' will not be', ' maybe wil be', ' will never be', ' must be ', ' must not be '],
  [' your end', ' your start', ' your future', ' your tasks', ' your past '],
]

// sentences for generatorTwo
let second = [
  ['Tulips', 'Roses', 'Daisys', 'Azaleas', 'Begonias', 'Gardenias'],
  [' are', ' are not', ' maybe are', ' maybe are not', ' have to be ', ' have not to be '],
  ['good ', ' awesome ', ' great ', ' red ', ' black '],
];

//generators
function generatorOne() {
  var gOne = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    gOne.push(first[i][Math.floor(Math.random() *
      first[i].length)]);
  }
  return gOne.join(" ");
}


function generatorTwo() {
  var gTwo = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < second.length; i++) {
    gTwo.push(second[i][Math.floor(Math.random() *
      second[i].length)]);
  }
  return gTwo.join(" ");
}

function generators() {
  var mix = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < mix; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("quoteChoice").value === '1') {
      generatorOne();
    } else if (document.getElementById("quoteChoice").value === '2' {
        generatorTwo();
      }
    }
  }


  function printQuote() {
    var pTag = document.getElementById("demo");
    pTag.innerText = generators();
  }

  printQuote();
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please see it is generating console errors and the formatting shows you have some bracket issues - I fixed the arrays - you should not have trailing commas btw

Answer (score 0):

function generators() doesn't return anything. Try

```
function generators() {
    var mix = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < mix; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("quoteChoice").value === '1') {
        return generatorOne();
    } else if (document.getElementById("quoteChoice").value === '2') {
        return generatorTwo();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the function but it is still not working :/

Comment: I believe it has to do with document.getElementById("quoteChoice").value you may be comparing the wrong value. Not sure what the context is but you may want to use document.getElementById("quoteChoice").innerText